# Postgresql execute procedure on update (value changed)

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I have the following `trigger` which calls the `update_recipe_timestamp_proc` `function` which updates the *modified_on* column.
If the same values gets inserted/updated the `trigger` is still triggered although there were no new values supplied!

#### Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_recipes_timestamp_r 
BEFORE UPDATE OF "identifier", "name", "description"
ON recipes 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_recipe_timestamp_proc();
```

#### Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_recipe_timestamp_proc()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW."modified_on" = now();
    RETURN NEW;   
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Do I have to program the logic in my function and return **NULL** or **NEW** based on the result or is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `UPDATE` is performed no matter if the new values are different from the old ones, and the same applies to triggers.

Three possible solutions:

1. As suggested by Sevanteri's comment, use

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER update_recipes_timestamp_r 
   BEFORE UPDATE OF "identifier", "name", "description"
   ON recipes FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (OLD IS DISTINCT FROM NEW)
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_recipe_timestamp_proc();
   ```
2. Write the trigger procedure like this:

   ```
   IF (OLD IS DISTINCT FROM NEW) THEN
      NEW."modified_on" = now();
      RETURN NEW;   
   END IF;
   ```
3. make the `UPDATE` conditional:

   ```
   UPDATE recipes
      SET "identifier" = val1, "name" = val2, "description" = val3
   WHERE ...
     AND "identifier" <> val1 OR "name" <> val2 OR "description" <> val3;
   ```

Comment: There is also the `WHEN` condition when creating the trigger. `WHEN (OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*)`

Comment: Right, that's even better!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I do not understand how I must use your solution. Maybe you could edit your or my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Is this better?

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `WHEN` to only update the *modified_on* column on specific column changes.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_recipes_timestamp_r BEFORE 
UPDATE ON recipes FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (
OLD."name" <> NEW."name" OR 
OLD."description" <> NEW."description" OR
OLD."identifier" <> NEW."identifier")
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_recipe_timestamp_proc();
```